# Force "submit for review" on update?

Tags: user-roles, capabilities, permissions

I'm trying to force all content to be submitted for review. That means that if a user updates an already published page, that the update would be pending until someone else approves it.

I don't see an option when looking at the wp's capabilities. Most role/cap plugins try to do too much and end up creating a mess. Any ideas?

I guess, a better question, is if there's a way to save a post as a revision, instead of updating it?

Answer (score 0):

The plugin Revisionary allow you to review post/page revisions before they go live. You can grab it for free here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/revisionary/

Comment: That plugin adds it's own review page which causes custom fields, and other plugins to break.

Comment: Really? Haven't had this problem myself. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. Tried it. So if the page/post has custom fields that only show up when you are on that page post, those fields won't load, because the plugin has it's own revision page. I am not sure if there's a way around that. I also noticed that other plugins that load with the editor had issues loading on that page.